# The meaning of "Your self worth down"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms

Would you please tell me what does "your self worth down" mean?

Here's part of the context

> you know what we have created a void inside our mind, the dog big space, which we constantly try to fill with others approval. the bigger the spaces, the more you are crushing your dreams, ***your self worth down***.

Comment: Are you sure that you copied this correctly? There are many irregularities. However, the bolded part could make sense if "down" were an adverb. (Note that "self worth" is a single phrase.)

Comment: It's syntactically sloppy, to say the least. But it's a "clipped" adverbial clause meaning ***causing your sense of self-respect to go down*** (because you're crushing your *own* ideals in seeking to gain the approval of others). Maybe "the **dog** big space" is a (poetic?, clumsy?) reference to ["**black dog**"](https://psychcentral.com/depression/black-dog-depression) = ***depression***.

Comment: I would read it as "You are crushing down your dreams and your self-worth."

Comment: The text might be better formatted to this: *You know what we have created? A void inside our mind, the big dog space, which we constantly try to fill with others approval. The bigger the spaces, the more you are crushing your dreams, your self worth, down.* The comma after "self worth" matches Kate Bunting's interpretation.

Comment: Jeffrey's suggestion of a parenthetical is more felicitous (admittedly to a poorly constructed original). It allows for your dreams / your self worth where / _could_ be Kates additive 'and' but _could_ show a corrective and/or expansive relation.